# Distance between point and convex set?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to compute the distance between a point in 3D and a convex set in 3D which is given as the intersection of halfplanes in numpy (python).

The distance between a point and a set is defined as the infimum (minimum) of the distance from the point and any point in the set.

Suppose the point is given as a 1D numpy array eg:

```
P = np.array([-1,-2,-3], ndmin = 1)
```

P represents the point (x,y,z) = (-1,-2,-3). And suppose the convex set is given as a 2D numpy array eg:

```
C = np.array([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8] , [9,10,11,12] )
```

C represents the convex set given by (x + 2y + 3y >= 4) /\ (5x + 6y + 7y >= 8) /\ (9x + 10y + 11y >= 12). How can I compute the distance between P and C? (We can assume that all halfplanes only use the operator >=)

**Note**: As mentioned by Pierre in the comments, the distance of the point is not just the minimum of the distance of the point and all line segments on the boundary of the halfplanes. We have to consider the faces of the convex set too.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. A point could be close to one of the half-planes and still far from all the line segments where that half-plane intersects with the other half-planes defining your convex set.

Comment: @PierreD Yes, and if you read the post carefully, I have mentioned that we must take the endpoints of the boundary of the original half plane (the line segment between these endpoints corresponds to the boundary of the half plane which intersects the other half planes), so even if a point is close to the boundary of the half plane, but it could be not close to the intersected boundary of the half plane which is the line segment.

Comment: Sorry, I am not following you. The half-planes intersect in line segments: yes. But those segments might be much farther away from `P` than the distance you are looking for. So the problem I have is with the statement: "the distance of a point that doesn't lie in the convex set from the convex set is the minimum distance of this point from all these line segments."

Comment: @PierreD Ok, I now understand your question. But I dont agree with "But those segments might be much farther away from P than the distance you are looking for. "
In my opinion, the distance will be exactly one of the distances of the point and some line segment. Isn't this so?

Comment: No. Picture one of the "facets" delimiting your convex set as being a triangle. `P` could be close to the center of the triangle (and just a bit away from that plane) and yet far from the sides of the triangle.

Comment: @PierreD Oh boy, I never even thought of convex sets which are restricted within some plane. Yes you are right, then even my attempt was incorrect. Do you know how I could solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way could be to consider the convex optimization (in this case a quadratic program) of finding the closest point to `P`, s.t. constraints that `Ax + b <= 0`. Note that there might be more efficient, specialized and accurate ways of doing this (see. e.g. [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/118093) and the links it refers to).

You can solve a convex problem using [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). Your half-spaces define the constraints, and the function to minimize is the distance (or its square) to the point `P`.

Note that we use the convention `Ax + b <= 0` for the half-spaces, and encode them `[A; b]`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint

def dist(x, p):
    return np.linalg.norm(x - p)

def find_closest(halfspaces, p):
    return minimize(
        dist, 
        np.zeros(3),
        args=(p,),
        constraints=[LinearConstraint(halfspaces[:, :-1], -np.inf, -halfspaces[:, -1])],
    )
```

As an example, consider the tetrahedron defined by the points `(0,0,0)`, `(2,0,0)`, `(1,2,0)`, and `(1,1,1)`:

```py
halfspaces = np.array(
    [[0,0,-1,0],  # Ax + b <= 0; each row of A is a vector normal to 
                  # hyperplane and pointing outside C
     [2,1,1,-4],
     [-2,1,1,0],
     [0,-1,1,0]])
```

Then:

```py
>>> find_closest(halfspaces, [0,0,10])
     fun: 9.110433579144301
     jac: array([ 0.10976422,  0.10976422, -0.98787833])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 12
     nit: 3
    njev: 3
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([1., 1., 1.])

# note: closest to a point (the top point)


>>> find_closest(halfspaces, [1,-0.1,0])
     fun: 0.10000032194980375
     jac: array([2.53758579e-03, 9.99996780e-01, 7.45058060e-08])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 13
     nit: 3
    njev: 3
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 1.00025375e+00, -2.22044605e-17,  6.04908606e-17])

# note: closest to an edge (the x-aligned line segment)


>>> find_closest(halfspaces, [1,1,-0.5])
     fun: 0.5000000000000011
     jac: array([0.00000000e+00, 5.96046448e-08, 1.00000000e+00])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 26
     nit: 6
    njev: 6
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([9.99999991e-01, 1.00000002e+00, 4.83315889e-16])

# note: closest to a face (the bottom face)
```